# htmlAttributes MVC 5.1 Editor for

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have added the following line to my view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, })
```

How do I access the htmlAttributes in the corresponding EditorTemplate Razor view?

Also how do I add some values to the existing passed in htmlAttributes in the EditorTemplate View?

Comment: If you really wanted to do that - I think you'd need to look into passing "htmlAttributes" as an ExpandoObject rather than an anonymous type. You could use an extension method or something similar to convert your object to an ExpandoObject.

Comment: @LeeGunn - You are apparently unaware that MVC 5.1 has added passing HtmlAttributes in EditorFor helpers, so this is now supported

Answer (score 15):

You can get them from the `ViewData`:

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    htmlAttributes.Add("key", "value"); //add new value
}
```

Comment: @model String

@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    htmlAttributes.Add("class", "form-control"); //add new value
}

@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, htmlAttributes)

Comment: We have to use "htmlAttributes["class"] += "k-textbox fc-url";" instead "htmlAttributes.Add("class", "k-textbox fc-url");"